# Primefaces dynamic tooltip

Tags: primefaces

I'm trying what I call a "dynamic tooltip" - I have a `inputNumber` field with a button and on button click I want to show tooltip if value is not poositive.

**Page**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:body>

    <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />

    <h:form>
        <p:outputLabel value="Enter positive integer" />
        <p:inputNumber id="val" value="#{dynamicTooltipView.val}" decimalPlaces="0" />
        <p:tooltip id="tooltip" for="val" value="Test" />
        <p:commandButton value="Validate" actionListener="#{dynamicTooltipView.validate}" update="val" process="val"/>
    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

**Bean**

```java
package com.codenotfound.primefaces.model;

import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class DynamicTooltipView {

    Integer val;
    boolean isValid;

    public void validate() {
        isValid = val != null && val > 0;
    }

    public Integer getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public void setVal(Integer val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public boolean isValid() {
        return isValid;
    }

    public void setValid(boolean isValid) {
        this.isValid = isValid;
    }

}
```

The problem is, that when I click the validate button, tooltip is lost and I do not understand why and how to fix it...

Comment: have you tried to add rendered="#{!dynamicTooltipView.isValid}" in your tooltip?

Comment: Or also update the tooltop?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mention that. 1.) `rendered="#{!dynamicTooltipView.isValid}"` is level two, but it is not working for default rendered value, which is true 2.) I tried that and it is not working...

Comment: Why it shouldn't work? I'm using it in my project too. Your commandButton needs the update attribute `update="val tooltip"`and the tooltip `rendered="#{!dynamicTooltipView.isValid}"`.

Comment: @lastresort Let me know if you cannot reproduce based on what I provided, "should work" is not helping anyone... My PF version is 6.2

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be in `process="val"`, when I specified this, my actionListener (`#{dynamicTooltipView.validate}`) is not called anymore (but I'd like to understand why)...

Additionally, `update="val tooltip"` is not working too, I had to specify `update="@form"` to make it work, but this is not exactly what I wanted...

I ended up with this solution (I used `p:fragment` without update on button):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
    <style>
        span.invalid>input {
            border-color: orange;
        }
    </style>
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <p:growl id="msgs"/>

    <h:form>
        <p:fragment autoUpdate="true">
            <p:outputLabel value="Enter positive integer" />
            <p:inputNumber id="val" value="#{dynamicTooltipView.val}" decimalPlaces="0" styleClass="#{dynamicTooltipView.isValid() ? '' : 'invalid'}"/>
            <p:tooltip id="tooltip" for="val" value="Entered value is not positive integer ;-)" rendered="#{dynamicTooltipView.isValid() == false}" />
            <p:commandButton value="Validate" actionListener="#{dynamicTooltipView.validate}" />
            <p:outputLabel value="#{dynamicTooltipView.isValid()}" />
        </p:fragment>
    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

`p:outputLabel` is there for debugging only...

Comment: The default value of  commandButton `process`  is `@form`, but if you specify a value it only process the mentioned components. So you just need to add `@this` to your process attribute to call your validate method. So you need to set `process="@this val"`:

Comment: @lastresort Thanks, it makes sense. I tried to specify `process="@this val"` and `update="@form"` for button, at least my listener is called, but tooltip is not updated (while input is - border was changed), which is strange...